# How to open my application when app link is clicked?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

What I want is to share the link of specific page of my application. Suppose I am in a profile page of some user in my app and I want to share that user to some of my friends so I would like to share it via WhatsApp and other applications.

So basically I want to share a link to my app.

This is what I am doing right now

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activity.getPackageName());
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

I know this is not what I really want but it's partially done.
if user hasn't installed my app then this code redirect him to google play store page to download this app.

Main problem is when user have already this app this link just opens the app. I want to redirect user to that specific page when he clicks on a link.

How can I do this?

I heard something about `intent-filter` but not sure how to use them.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
```

**UPDATED**

Now I am trying to share my app link like this

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra("PostID", postID);
    shareIntent.putExtra("UserID", userID);
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activity.getPackageName());
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

Inside my manifest I have declared an activity like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.ShareActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="details"
                android:scheme="market" />
            <data
                android:host="play.google.com"
                android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=my_package_name"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="play.google.com"
                android:pathPattern="/store/apps/details?id=my_package_name"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But I am still not able to see my app when I click on the link I shared using WhatsApp or any other means.

Please help me

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of deep linking?  http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 3):

Add the following intent-filters to your activity declaration, in the AndroidManifest of your project :

```
    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>

    </intent-filter>
```

Now, in the **onCreate()**, **onResume()** or **onNewIntent()** method of your activity lifecycle, you can use the **getData()** of the **intent** that has fired your activity.

Comment: And to pass the data suppose userID i put the extra in the sharing intent??

Comment: Yes you can pass any kind of data to your intent. You can take a look at this for more information.http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: can you see me updated question and tell me what i am doing wrong